# event check only when clicked on a button

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a simple test script, which it meant to change a boolean when the user clicks within the dimensions of the button but it is not working.

I approached it like so:

```
while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ) {
        switch( event.type ){
            case SDL_QUIT: quit = true; break;
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION: mouseX = event.motion.x; mouseY = event.motion.y; break;    
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: click = true; 
        }
}
 Button btn_settings(btn_x,btn_y);
 if(btn_settings.IsIn(mouseX,mouseY)){
    btn_settings.RenderImg(menu,screen,"button_on.png","Settings");

    if(click){
        quit = true;
    }

 } else {
    btn_settings.RenderImg(menu,screen,"button.png","Settings");
 }
```

The problem is if i click any where then click equals true, then if the mouse is `over` the quit button it exits even if the button wasn't pressed when over the button.

I'm confused how i can make it work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try handling your "click" event on mouse button up instead. I've never used SDL but I suspect there is a `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP` defined. Otherwise you don't know if they want to perform a drag operation or if they moved the mouse someplace else before letting go of the mouse button.

Comment: Would i place that inside the "IsIn" if statement?